# jQuery Selector corresponding image and li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm wanting to change the list-style of the li tag after the corresponding image has been clicked. This is what I have got so far.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLnark6p/)

```js
$('#foodOrder').click(function() {
      $(this " > li").css('list-style', 'disc');
    });
```

```css
#foodOrder {
  list-style: circle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="foodOrder"><img id="orderFood" src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" alt="" /><li>CIABATTA</li></span>
      <span id="foodOrder"><img id="orderFood" src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" alt="" /><li>BAKERS BUN</li></span>
```

Comment: `$(this).children('li')` or `$('> li', this)`. But wait, your HTML markup is invalid... `li` can only be child of `ul/ol/template` and IDs must be unique on document context. BTW, you didn't include jQuery in jsFiddle. So that's make many things wrong for so little snippet....

Comment: it only works for one of them?

Comment: Here is fixed jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gLnark6p/2/  Maybe it would help you to get what you were doing wrong

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it :P Now I'll know what to do next time!

Comment: @A.Wolff your HTML is invalid too: unnecessary second `</ul>` and you shouldn't put `<ul>` inside `<span>`, read my answer.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Ya good point but extra `</ul>` was because of new jsFiddle autocompletation option, i should surely disable it... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your jQuery selector (syntax mistake) and HTML:

1. [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) must be only in [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) or [`<menu>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu).
2. [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) must contain only [`Phrasing content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) is [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content). You should use [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) then.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/fk58hbpb/1/)

```js
$('.foodOrder').click(function() {
    $('li', this).css('list-style', 'disc');
});
```

```css
.foodOrder li {
    list-style: circle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foodOrder">
    <img class="orderFood" src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" alt=""/>
    <ul>
        <li>CIABATTA</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="foodOrder">
    <img class="orderFood" src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" alt=""/>
    <ul>
        <li>BAKERS BUN</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```